# How to caculated the overall distance of points of the whole link list in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, distance

I'm have a node list like this:
(0,0) -> (0,3) -> (4,3) -> null
I'm trying to write a method to caculate the distance of node list, but the output does not seem right.

Here is my Program. I have 2 class, waypoint to create a newpoint in the linked list, and TourElement contains points.

//WayPoint.java:

```
public class Waypoint {
    int x  ;
    int y  ;
    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
    public void setXY(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
     double calcDistance(Waypoint other) {
            //(0,0),(0,4)
     double X = other.x - getX();//3
     double Y = other.y - getY();//3
     return Math.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);
    }
```

//TourElement.java

```
public class TourElement {
 private Waypoint points;
 private TourElement next;
  public void setWaypoint( Waypoint points)
 {
   this.points = points; 
 }
  public void setTourElement(TourElement next)
  {
      this.next = next;
  }
 Waypoint getWaypoint()
 {
     return this.points;
 }




TourElement getNext()
 {
     return this.next;
 }
```

// the output of this method does not seem right

```
double calcDistance()
{
  double distance = 0;
  TourElement current = this;

  while (current.next != null)
  {
 distance = distance  + current.points.calcDistance(this.points);
      current = current.next;
  }
  if(current.next == null)
  {
      distance = distance + current.points.calcDistance(points);
  }
  return distance;
}
```

//the test case:

```
private TourElement createElementList(int[][] waypoints){
        assert waypoints.length > 0;
        TourElement elem = new TourElement();
        int lastIndex = waypoints.length-1;
        Waypoint wp = createWaypoint(waypoints[lastIndex][0], waypoints[lastIndex][1]);
        elem.setWaypoint(wp);
        for (int i = lastIndex-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            wp = createWaypoint(waypoints[i][0], waypoints[i][1]);
            elem = elem.addStart(wp);
        }
        return elem;
    }

  public void testCalcDistance_ThreeElementsOrthogonal() {
        TourElement elem = createElementList(new int[][] {{0, 0}, {0, 3}, {4, 3}});
        assertEquals(7, elem.calcDistance(), EPSILON);
    }
```

When I test my method, in the while loop, distance = (0,0) and (0,3), it right. but then, when I try to caculate the distance of 2 point (0,3) and (4,3), the output is wrong because the program caculate the distance (0,0) and (4,3) instead of (0,3) and(4,3). so the out put is 8. I dont know what I'm doing wrong, pls help me. thank you a lot in advance!!!!

Comment: Look hard at `current.points.calcDistance(this.points)`: what is it doing and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I want to sum two points(0,0) and (0,3). the result is three. then, I want to caculate 2 next points in the linked list (0,3) and (4,3). the result is 4. then I sum 2 distance and the output is 7.

Comment: Does `current.points.calcDistance(this.points)` give you the distance between the current point and the next point, or between the current point and the first point? What would you expect to see in the expression if you were referring to the "next point"?

Comment: additionally: `current` == `this` when starting (despite checking `current.next` - kind of strange, at least). And another point, despite not wrong, just *strange*: when calculating distance, accessing `x` and `y` directly from `other` but through getters of own instance.